# Wired networking problem on an Acer am350 netbook

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless, acer

Am a linux newbie and I recently insatalled ubuntu Maverick Meekart on my netbook. I usually use wifi or a wired network for internet.

However after using it for a couple of days without a hitch I cannot connect to the internet anymore because whenever a hook the cable to the RJ45 connector or I turn on wifi to use the wireless hotspots in school the system starts searching but to my utter diassapointment when it finishes instead of connecting I am notified that the connection has been disconnected and I am now offline.

This is the fact that wifi is on and/or the RJ45 connector is correctly hooked. Please help. Because am really starting to like my new OS and wouldnt want to dump it and re-install windows

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct **pass phrase** and **SSID** for the school connection? Otherwise your connection might be rejected.

On the Upper Right Panel, **Left clicking** on the **connection icon**, shows you available wireless connection the system has found. Click on the correct **SSID** and when prompted type the **CORRECT password**.

When using a **cat5** cable make sure **Auto eth0** is active, click on it to turn it off, click again to turn on.

**Right clicking** on the **connection icon**, Gives you to the option to **enable wireless**, and **enable networking**. Enable Networking is for the cat5 cable. ***If I'm using cat5, I usually right click on the connection icon and disable wireless.***

**Right clicking** the **connection icon**, you can see **connection information**. This will tell you what **ip address** you machine has been given by the server. The **MAC** address of your **eth0 card**, the **connection speed**, etc.

If you want your machine to automatically connect to the hotspot (making sure you have all the required and correct information from the school) **Right click** on the **connection icon**, click **Edit Connections**, **Add Wireless** and put all the info into the correct sections.

I usually connect to **hidden wireless connections**. I just **left click** the **connection icon**, and choose **Connect to Hidden Wireless Connection**, on the **connection input box** there is a **drop down**, click on the **drop down** (inverted triangle) to see networks you normally connect to. I just choose one of the many pre-configured connections, and click the **connect button**.

Also check that the wireless is **physically turned on** the laptop/netbook, usually a keyboard combination key **FN plus a function key**, or a **slider button** on the **side** or **front** of the laptop/netbook.

Let me know if you need more help. When asking for help give more details on your machine, manufacture and model of notebook etc.